# using a wildcard in awk

Tags: awk, wildcard

Using awk, I want to print all lines that have a string in the first column that starts with 22_

I tried the following, but obviously * does not work as a wildcard in awk:

```
awk '$1=="22_*" {print $0}' input > output
```

Is this possible in awk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with a test file:

```
$ cat >file
22_something keep
23_other omit
```

To keep only lines that start with `22_`:

```
$ awk '/^22_/' file
22_something keep
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to reference the first field explicitly, we could use:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^22_/' file
22_something keep
```

Note that we don't have to write `{print $0}` after the condition because that is exactly the default action that `awk` associates with a condition.

At the start of a regular expressions, `^` matches the beginning of a line.  Thus, if you want `22_` to occur at the start of a line or the start of a field, you want to write `^22_`.

In the condition `$1 ~ /^22_/`, note that the operator is `~`.  That operator tells `awk` to check if the preceding string, `$1`, matches the regular expression `^22_`.

Answer (score 3):

Chosen answer does not answer how to use a wildcard in awk, which is achieved using `.*` (instead of `*`):

```
awk '$1=="22_.*" {print $0}' input > output
```